# How to call a function every n seconds?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I do:

```
def my_api_query():
    pass

while True:
    my_api_query()
    time.sleep(5)
```

This would work like execution time of `my_api_query()` plus 5 seconds, which is longer than 5 seconds.

I want one iteration to be executed exactly every 5th second.

How can I implement it in Python 3?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution, need to test it, any other suggestions are welcome:

```
import threading

def my_api_query():
  threading.Timer(5.0, my_api_query).start()
  some code

my_api_query()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is quite clumsy, but should be working

```
import time
nexttime = time.time()
while True:
    my_api_query()          # take t sec
    nexttime += 10
    sleeptime = nexttime - time.time()
    if sleeptime > 0:
        time.sleep(sleeptime)
```